# What level needed to get the dragonvale races?

Tags: dragonvale

I want to get dragonvale races but I don't have the level required to get it. What level is needed for the track

Answer (score 2):

To build the [Dragon Track](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Track), you need to be level 15.

Answer (score 0):

**Level 15.** 
I just got to level 16 and I got the dragon races at 15; you must have been at a lower level.